# JavaScript function will open div tag; second JavaScript function does not close it however

Tags: javascript, html, function, popup

I have been browsing here and looking at similar problems, however none of the solutions seem to work. This is also my first posted question.

```html
<table>
<tr class="foo" onclick="openEmail1();">...</tr>
<tr class="foo" onclick="openEmail2();">...</tr>
<tr class="foo" onclick="openEmail3();"> <!-- this opens fine-->
  <td>From: Me</td>
  <td>Subject: Why won't this work?</td>
  <td>Date:

  <div style="display: none" id="email3">..email popup..

    <div>...header box in email popup...</div>
    <div>...email body box in email popup...</div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="openForm();">Forward</button> <!-- this works fine-->
      <button onclick="closeEmail3();">Close</button> <!-- does not work-->
    </div>

  </div>
  <script>
  function openEmail3(){
    document.getElementById("email3").style.display = "block";
  }
  function closeEmail3(){
    document.getElementById("email3").style.display = "none";
  }
  </script>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is just a pseudo code but I ran this and it works(or doesn't work) exactly how mine does. I do not understand why the closeEmail function is not working.

Comment: Don't provide pseudo code that doesn't reproduce your problem. Write a [mcve].

Comment: I feel I have answered your question with a working example that shows your desired functionality. If this is correct, please click the checkmark to mark the answer correct since it will also help others looking for the same solution. - Thanks, and happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because of [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

I've updated your code to be more legible by putting your element in a var

```
 var div = document.getElementById("email3");
```

Changing your button element to this will stop the default functionality

```
<button onclick="closeEmail3();event.stopPropagation()">Close</button>
```

Run the snippet below to see it in action.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("email3");
 
 function openEmail3(){
    if  (div.style.display === "none") {
    div.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
    div.style.display === "none" }
  }
  
  function closeEmail3(){
    if  (div.style.display === "block") {
    div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="foo" onclick="openEmail1();">...</tr>
<tr class="foo" onclick="openEmail3();"> <!-- this opens fine-->
  <td>From: Me</td>
  <td>Subject: Why won't this work?</td>
  <td>Date:

  <div style="display: none" id="email3">..email popup..

    <div>...header box in email popup...</div>
    <div>...email body box in email popup...</div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="openForm();">Forward</button> <!-- this works fine-->
      <button onclick="closeEmail3();event.stopPropagation()">Close</button> <!-- does not work-->
    </div>

  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use This**

```
<button type="button" onclick="closeEmail3();">Close</button>
```

OR

```
<input type="button" onclick="closeEmail3();" value="Close" />
```